# progress bar in php & jquery

Tags: php, jquery, zend-mail

i have a PHP process who send X mails
After each mail send, i add a line on a database for tell that a mail is send.

So, i wan't to create a progress bar for tell to the user that X mails are sended on Y ( Y = total)

I have two jquery function like that :

```
function mail_send()
{
    $('.loading').css('display','block');
    $.ajax({
        'url': '/an/url/', 
        'data': {
                    someParam: param
                },
        'beforeSend':function()
                    {
                        $('#loadingBg').append('<span id="count"></span>');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            mail_updateProgress(id);
                        }, 500);
                    }

        , 
        'success':  function (data,textStatus)
                    {
                       (....)
                    }
    });
}

function mail_updateProgress(id) {
    $.ajax({
        'url': '/an/url/', 
            'data': {
                        someParam: param
                    },
        'success':  function (data) {
                        var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                        $('#count').html(res.nbSended + '/' + res.total);
                    }
    });
}
```

The problem is that i can't send more than 15 mail right now and i'll not create XXX mail adresses for test it, but the updateProgress() function just success one time and it's happen in the same time of the mail_send() function.

Is there an error ?

thanks

EDIT : 
Ok, so setInterval is good, but i have a second problem, Is there a queue for the $.ajax ?
I'm loggin 3 things :
first : When the process is enter on the updateProgress function
second : when the updateProgress ajax is successed
third : When the mail_send() ajax is successed

the order of the log is

fisrt (X times )
Third (1time)
second(X times)

so, my progress bar never progress, just make 0% => 100% when the send function is ended

any idea to process the progress function while the send function ?
is it possible to delegate ?

Comment: What is the point of the `id` variable? You don't seem to use it anywhere - is there more code you're not showing us?

Comment: I have "modify" my code to show you, i'm realy using it ;)

Comment: you probably want to move the updateProgress to the success? why are you checking it beforeSend? how do you initiate mail_send

Comment: i'm initialize my setInterval before start my send() ajax, but i want to check my progression each 500ms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using **setTimeout** If you want intervalled checking use: **setInterval**.

Comment: Ok for the SetInterval, but i have a second probleme, the mail_updateProgress() success is only call when the newsletter_send() ajax is ended

Comment: It would be nice to see some server side code to see if there's something causing the progress updater -request to wait until all mail has been handled.